# How to get value of a column before it was changed

Tags: workflow

In SharePoint designer or Nintex workflow is it possible to check what the value of a list column was before it was updated? I need to perform certain operation based on the early values.

In SharePoint event receivers we can do this by using Before-properties. Is there any similar functionality in workflow as well?

Answer (score 1):

I know you can make a workflow to trigger when an item is modified and also that you can configure the start conditional to use built-in logic that basically captures the previous value but this functionality doesn't seem to be available in any workflow actions.

If you have Nintex Forms then you could edit the list form to hide all of the controls directly linked to your list columns with the IsEditMode() rule applied to a Panel. You would need to recreate all of these labels/controls and add them to a second panel control which would be hidden using the rule IsNewMode().

By doing this you could tie in a workflow that first logs all of the information in your list columns to the history list and then update your list columns with the values entered into the controls within the IsEditMode() Panel via the update list action.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you are updating the column value from the workflow itself, then you can track the column value by reading the listitem. If someone changes the value from the UI or programmatically , i think there is no other way than event receivers to get before and after properties.

Comment: Yes, we can get before and after properties using event receivers. And I didn't find any such in SPD and Nintex workflows. Did you ever happen to deal with any other workflow that provide this functionality?

Comment: I don't think SPD and nintex workflow provide these kind of activities or any other third party workflows.